# Arduino Android Bluetooth Communication

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, communication

I've made an app which connects to Arduino Mega 2560 by means of HC-05 Bluetooth module.
I succeed in giving commands to Arduino via bluetooth, but the opposite communication doesn't apparently work. I don't know if the problem is in Arduino or Android side.

Arduino sends messages with this simple instructions:
    #include 
    ...
    SoftwareSerial bluetooth(12, 11);

```
void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    bluetooth.begin(9600);
    ...
}

void loop(){
    ...
    bluetooth.listen();
    while (bluetooth.available() > 0) {
        char inByte = bluetooth.read();     
        if(inByte == '0') {   
            bluetooth.print('a');
            delay(500);
        }
    }
    ...

}
```

Instead Android Code is the following:

```
package com.example.arduo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button Connect;
    ToggleButton OnOff;
    TextView Result;
    private String dataToSend;

    private static final String TAG = "Jon";
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private OutputStream outStream = null;
    private static String address = "00:14:02:13:00:10";
    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID
                    .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    private InputStream inStream = null;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    byte delimiter = 10;
    boolean stopWorker = false;
    int readBufferPosition = 0;
    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
            OnOff = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tgOnOff);
            Result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msgJonduino);

            Connect.setOnClickListener(this);
            OnOff.setOnClickListener(this);

            CheckBt();
            BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
            Log.e("Jon", device.toString());

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View control) {
            switch (control.getId()) {
            case R.id.connect:
                            Connect();
                    break;
            case R.id.tgOnOff:
                    if (OnOff.isChecked()) {
                            dataToSend = "1";
                            writeData(dataToSend);
                    } else if (!OnOff.isChecked()) {
                            dataToSend = "0";
                            writeData(dataToSend);
                    }
                    break;
            }
    }

    private void CheckBt() {
            mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth Disabled !",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Bluetooth null !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
            }
    }

            public void Connect() {
                    Log.d(TAG, address);
                    BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connecting to ... " + device);
                    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                    try {
                            btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
                            btSocket.connect();
                            Log.d(TAG, "Connection made.");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connessione effettuata",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                            try {
                                    btSocket.close();
                            } catch (IOException e2) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Unable to end the connection");
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Impossibile terminare la connessione",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            Log.d(TAG, "Socket creation failed");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Creazione socket fallita.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    beginListenForData();
            }

    private void writeData(String data) {
            try {
                    outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Bug BEFORE Sending stuff", e);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bug prima di mandare i dati",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            String message = data;
            byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();

            try {
                    outStream.write(msgBuffer);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dati inviati correttamente",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Bug while sending stuff", e);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bug mandando i dati",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            try {
                 btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
    }

    public void beginListenForData()   {
            try {
                 inStream = btSocket.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            Thread workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {                
                   while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
                   {
                        try
                        {
                            int bytesAvailable = inStream.available();                        
                            if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                            {
                                byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                                inStream.read(packetBytes);
                                for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                                {
                                    byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                    if(b == delimiter)
                                    {
                                        byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                        System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                        final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                        readBufferPosition = 0;
                                        handler.post(new Runnable()
                                        {
                                            public void run()
                                            {

                                                   //     if(Result.getText().toString().equals("..")) {
                                                            Result.setText(data);
                                                                                                                         // } else {
                                                    //        Result.append("\n"+data);
                                                    //}

                                                    /* You also can use Result.setText(data); it won't display multilines
                                                    */

                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (IOException ex)
                        {
                            stopWorker = true;

                        }
                   }
                }
            });

            workerThread.start();
        }
```

}

Does anybody know why Android doesn't receive or simply display the character sent by Arduino?
Thanks everybody!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way it works. Just I've changed the Android code with this one, it can be useful for somebody who has the same problem!

```
package bt.andard.btandard;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private static final String TAG = "bluetooth2";

  Button btnOn, btnOff;
  TextView txtArduino;
  Handler h;

  final int RECEIVE_MESSAGE = 1;    //1    // Status  for Handler
  private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
  private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
  private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

  // SPP UUID service
  private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

  // MAC-address of Bluetooth module (you must edit this line)
  private static String address = "00:14:02:13:00:10";

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     btnOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOn);                  // button LED ON
     btnOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOff);                // button LED OFF
     txtArduino = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtArduino);      // for display the received data             from the Arduino

     h = new Handler() {
     public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case RECEIVE_MESSAGE:                                   // if receive massage
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1); // create string from bytes array
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), strIncom, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            sb.append(strIncom);                                                // append string
            int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n");                            // determine the end-of-line
            if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                            // if end-of-line,
                String sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);               // extract string
                sb.delete(0, sb.length());                                      // and clear
                txtArduino.setText("Data from Arduino: " + strIncom);            // update TextView
              //  btnOff.setEnabled(true);
              //  btnOn.setEnabled(true); 
            }
            //Log.d(TAG, "...String:"+ sb.toString() +  "Byte:" + msg.arg1 + "...");
            break;
        }
    };
};

btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();       // get Bluetooth adapter
checkBTState();

btnOn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
  //  btnOn.setEnabled(false);
    mConnectedThread.write("1");    // Send "1" via Bluetooth
    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn on LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});

btnOff.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
  //  btnOff.setEnabled(false);  
      mConnectedThread.write("0");    // Send "0" via Bluetooth
    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn off LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  });
}

private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10){
        try {
            final Method  m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", new Class[] { UUID.class });
          return (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, MY_UUID);
       } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Could not create Insecure RFComm Connection",e);
    }
  }
  return  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();

  Log.d(TAG, "...onResume - try connect...");

  // Set up a pointer to the remote node using it's address.
  BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

  // Two things are needed to make a connection:
  //   A MAC address, which we got above.
  //   A Service ID or UUID.  In this case we are using the
  //     UUID for SPP.

   try {
       btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
   } catch (IOException e) {
       errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
 }

 // Discovery is resource intensive.  Make sure it isn't going on
 // when you attempt to connect and pass your message.
 btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

 // Establish the connection.  This will block until it connects.
 Log.d(TAG, "...Connecting...");
 try {
     btSocket.connect();
     Log.d(TAG, "....Connection ok...");
 } catch (IOException e) {
 try {
     btSocket.close();
 } catch (IOException e2) {
     errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure" + e2.getMessage() + ".");
 }
}

 // Create a data stream so we can talk to server.
 Log.d(TAG, "...Create Socket...");

 mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
 mConnectedThread.start();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
  super.onPause();

  Log.d(TAG, "...In onPause()...");

  try     {
     btSocket.close();
  } catch (IOException e2) {
     errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to close socket." + e2.getMessage() + ".");
  }
}

private void checkBTState() {
   // Check for Bluetooth support and then check to make sure it is turned on
   // Emulator doesn't support Bluetooth and will return null
   if(btAdapter==null) { 
      errorExit("Fatal Error", "Bluetooth not support");
   } else {
   if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
       Log.d(TAG, "...Bluetooth ON...");
   } else {
       //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
       Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
       startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
   }
  }
 }

private void errorExit(String title, String message){
   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), title + " - " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   finish();
}

 private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
     private final InputStream mmInStream;
     private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

     public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        // member streams are final
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);        // Get number of bytes and message in "buffer"
                h.obtainMessage(RECEIVE_MESSAGE, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();     // Send to message queue Handler
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(String message) {
        Log.d(TAG, "...Data to send: " + message + "...");
        byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "...Error data send: " + e.getMessage() + "...");     
          }
    }
   }
}
```